# Are JavaScript DOM event handlers called in order of registration?

Tags: javascript, dom, events, event-handling, dom-events

If I attach multiple event handlers to a single event on a single DOM element, are the event handlers guaranteed to be called in the order they were added? Or should I not rely on this behavior?

Comment: to supplement, see also [What is the order of inline onclick vs addeventlistener and why?](/q/49805942/11107541)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This [has been changed](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#changes-DOMEvents2to3Changes-flow) with DOM3! While the [DOM level 2 events specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-basic) did state

> When the event reaches the target, any event listeners registered on the
> [`EventTarget`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventTarget)
> are triggered. Although all [`EventListeners`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventListener)
> on the `EventTarget` are guaranteed to be triggered by any event which
> is received by that `EventTarget`, **no specification** is made as **to the
> order** in which they will receive the event with regards to the other
> `EventListeners` on the `EventTarget`.

The current [DOM level 3 events specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow) does now state

> The implementation MUST determine the current target's [candidate
> event listeners](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#candidate-event-handlers).
> This MUST be the list of all event listeners that have been registered
> on the current target **in their order of registration**. `HTML5`
> defines the ordering of listeners [registered through event handler
> attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-handler-content-event-handler-content-attribute).
> […]
>
> Finally, the implementation MUST process all candidate [event
> handlers](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#glossary-event-handler)
> **in order** […]

However, I can't find a reference to this behaviour in the [DOM 4 draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-event-dispatch) any more.

Comment: Presumably if this comes from HTML5 it means that current browsers already do this, do you think?

Comment: @thomasrutter: Yes, pretty much - they only standardise what they implement.

Comment: The answer appears to be out of date. The current DOM Level 3 spec doesn't include the quoted paragraph about candidate event listeners anymore, unfortunately.