# Get if checkbox is checked or not in jquery/ES6

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

Following is my jQuery code by which I am trying to retrieve whether the checkbox is clicked or not. I used both `is` and `prop` but somehow its always returning `false` and `undefined` in console. Let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Also, let me know the more better way to handle the checkbox value is to target the `click` or `change` event on checkbox( currently I am listening to `click` event).

**jQuery Code -**

```
const $document = $(document);
$document.ready(() => {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").on('click', () => {
        console.log("Checked Value 'is' :: ", $(this).is(':checked'));
        console.log("Checked Value 'prop' :: ", $(this).prop('checked'));
    })
})
```

**HTML CODE -**

```
<form name="myForm" id="#myForm">
    <div>
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="accept-t-and-c" /> I accept terms and conditions</p>
    </div>
    <div>   
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>  
</form>
```

**JSFIDDLE -**  https://jsfiddle.net/82Lz1c8w/4/

**EDIT -**
Few of the folks before getting into the question just marking it as duplicate however in this case the solution that they are referring with the below mentioned links won't work as I am using arrow functions and its changing the context. Please read the answers for the support.

Comment: this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204250/check-if-checkbox-is-checked-with-jquery

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2204275/5985593

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if checkbox is checked with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204250/check-if-checkbox-is-checked-with-jquery)

Comment: @thedude I checked this post as well and in that same thread they mentioned is and prop use, now my code is not working and I posted the scenario ..so this cannot be treated as duplicate

Comment: Use `change` instead of `click`.

Comment: Just because **click** and **change** events has a different order in different browsers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25014911/is-there-a-standard-for-the-event-order-of-click-and-change-on-a-checkbox/25093845#25093845

Comment: @thedude It isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use normal function. When arrow syntax is used, `this` inside it will refer to the enclosing context. Also, use `change` event.

[No binding of `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this)

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function() {
    console.log("Checked Value 'is' :: ", $(this).is(':checked'));
    console.log("Checked Value 'prop' :: ", $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/82Lz1c8w/5/)

```js
$("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function() {
  console.log("Checked Value 'is' :: ", $(this).is(':checked'));
  console.log("Checked Value 'prop' :: ", $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="accept-t-and-c" /> I accept terms and conditions</p>
```

Comment: Thx a lot for the info...I am really fascinated by `this` in arrow functions :)

Answer (score 2):

Try below code:

```
 $("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', (e) => {
      console.log("Checked Value 'is' :: ", e.currentTarget.checked);
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use that syntax you need to change your code to

```
$document.ready(() => {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").on('click', (e) => {
        console.log("Checked Value 'is' :: ", $(e.target).is(':checked'));
        console.log("Checked Value 'prop' :: ", $(e.target).prop('checked'));
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Working code:

```
const $document = $(document);
$document.ready(() => {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").on('click', (e) => {
        const selfEvent = $(e.currentTarget)
        console.log(selfEvent)
        console.log("Checked Value 'is' :: ", selfEvent.is(':checked'));
        console.log("Checked Value 'prop' :: ", selfEvent.prop('checked'));
    })
})
```

Please note that `this` refers to `window` object.

Answer (score 1):

Please replace javascript with below code

```
const $document = $(document);
    $document.ready(function() {
        $("input[type='checkbox']").on('click', function(){
            console.log("Checked Value 'is' :: ", $(this).is(':checked'));
    console.log("Checked Value 'prop' :: ", $(this).prop('checked'));
    })
```

})

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {
      console.log("Checked Value 'is' :: ", $(this).is(':checked'));
      console.log("Checked Value 'prop' :: ", $(this).prop('checked'));
   })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="myForm" id="#myForm">
 <div>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="accept-t-and-c" /> I accept terms and conditions</p>
 </div>
 <div> 
  <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
 </div> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you shouldn't use arrow-function because of in arrow-function,`this` is point to parent scope.you can try replace

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").on('click', () => {
    console.log("Checked Value 'is' :: ", $(this).is(':checked'));
    console.log("Checked Value 'prop' :: ", $(this).prop('checked'));
})
```

with

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").on('click', function() {
    console.log("Checked Value 'is' :: ", $(this).is(':checked'));
    console.log("Checked Value 'prop' :: ", $(this).prop('checked'));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ES6 you may do something like the above,

```
document.querySelector("input[name='accept-t-and-c']").onchange = function() {
    if(this.checked)
        console.log("Checkbox is checked");
    else
        console.log("Checkbox is not checked");
};
```