# Vue.js Checkbox issue in Firefox, works file in Chrome and IE

Tags: vue.js

I am using a checkbox.

```
<template v-for="(item,index) in items">
    <div >
        <input type="checkbox"  
            v-model="item.checked"
            @click="selectionCheckboxClicked(index,item.checked)"   
        />
    </div>          
    .....
```

And this is the JS code

```
selectionCheckboxClicked: function selectionCheckboxClicked(index,checked) {
            console.log(this.items[index].checked);
            console.log(checked);
            ....
        },
```

Initial value of item.checked is false. When I click the checkbox in Chrome or IE, it checks the checkbox and displays 'true' in console log. However, when I run the code in Firefox, though it does change the state, console log displays false in selectionCheckboxClicked(). I need to take some action based on the current state of the checkbox in selectionCheckboxClicked(), which I ma finding difficult to implement in the current situation.

Shall appreciate any suggestions to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Because** for **checkbox**, `v-model` bind `@change` not `@input` (check [Vue Github: source codes for v-model](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/platforms/web/compiler/directives/model.js#L82)). Then `@change` will be fired after lose focus.

But you **should not** rely on the order either `@click` or `@change` will be executed first ([check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25093845/5665870) for more details).

So **one solution** is uses `@change=handler($event)` instead, because `v-model` uses `addHandler` with [one parameter named important=true](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/platforms/web/compiler/directives/model.js#L92) to make sure it will be fired first than your event handler.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      testValues: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    selectionCheckboxClicked: function(ev) {
      console.log(this.testValues);
      console.log(ev.target.checked);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="testValues" @change="selectionCheckboxClicked($event)" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Or **another solution** is uses `@input` but you should rely on what is checked or not on the input Dom element.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      testValues: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    selectionCheckboxClicked: function(ev) {
      console.log('v-model:', this.testValues);
      console.log('inputCheckedAtDom:', ev.target.checked);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="testValues" @input="selectionCheckboxClicked($event)" />
  </div>
</div>
```

If you still like to use `@click`, one solution actually is same as `@input`. Uses one `ref` to access the input Dom element.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      testValues: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    selectionCheckboxClicked: function(ev) {
      console.log('v-model:', this.testValues);
      console.log('inputCheckedAtDom:', this.$refs.test.checked);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <input ref="test" type="checkbox" v-model="testValues" @click="selectionCheckboxClicked($event)" />
  </div>
</div>
```

setTimeout will work because it will be executed **after current task finished and re-render**. Even you uses `setTimeout(()=>{}, 0)`(delay **0 seconds**), it will still work.

Comment: Thanks for providing such a detailed answer!

Answer (score 0):

What seems to be happening is that Firefox calls the click function immediately even before the **v-model = "item.checked"** has changes. When I check the value of **this.items[index].checked** after some delay (say 100 ms), it displays true.

console.log(this.items[index].checked);
        console.log(checked);

```
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function()
        { if (self.items[index].checked)
                self.selectedContactsCount++; 
              else
                  self.selectedContactsCount--; 
             },
            100);
```