# Order of execution of functions bound to an event in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, browser

I was searching for details regarding the order of execution of functions bound to a page event in javascript, for example via an EventListener.

For example, if I bind three functions A(), B() and C(), to the same event (say DOMContentLoaded), what will be the order of execution of these three functions?
One-by-one based on the order of addEventListener call in JS code? Or they are executed all simultaneously?

Besides, can I modify this order? For example, to have a function, bound to DOMContentLoaded event listener, to be executed before any other function bound to the same event.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers; I understand that the order of execution is based on the order of addEventListener call(s). But, how can I be sure that my function will be the first to be called when the page fires the DOMContentLoaded event? I should just place the js script *before* anything else in the page? Does it make differences the fact that the script is in-line or an external file?

Comment: Unless your control the page you don’t know if another event listener has been added previously. This question has multiple ways of checking and it seems there is a function that can check but it might only workin the developer console https://stackoverflow.com/a/16544813. Hopefully it will be available outsides if the developer console.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are JavaScript DOM event handlers called in order of registration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706109/are-javascript-dom-event-handlers-called-in-order-of-registration)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Event handlers are always called in the order in which they were registered.

Once registered, you cannot insert additional handlers ahead of them[*].

---

[*] unless you are some how able to obtain a list of all the handlers, and their `EventListener` objects, and call `removeEventListener` to remove them, insert your own, and then reinsert the originals.  In practise this is likely to be impossible.

Comment: In DOM2, the specification explicitly says that the order in which the handlers attached to an element are called is not guaranteed; but DOM3 changes that, saying that handlers are called in the order in which they're registered.

Comment: Can you please give a link to the DOM3 specification? Thanks.

Comment: @QianChen FYI nothing is listed on MDN in order of execution https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 5):

```
var listeners = [];

//add listeners in whatever order you want them executed

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    for (var i = 0; i < listeners.length; i++) {
        listeners[i]();
    }
});
```