# Multiple Listeners for Single Event

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

In JavaScript we are allowed to set the multiple listeners on the single event. For example:

```
element.addEventListener('click',startDragDrop,false);
element.addEventListener('click',spyOnUser,false);
```

I am planning to do the same in my project. I just want to be sure that it should not cause any problem with the order of the execution of the callback the way it is written on [QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html). It says that **W3C model does not state which event handler is fired first, so you cannot assume `startDragDrop()` is executed before `spyOnUser()`.** But I want to be sure that my `startDragDrop` should be executed first then `spyOnUser()`. Is there any way I can make it sure?

Comment: Yes, that's why it's called *add*EventListener and not *set*EventListener.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25016769/1984039

Comment: As per the previous comment's link, order is guaranteed by the newer spec. But if you want to support really old browsers you'd have to use your own event binding proxy to control order, or use a library (e.g. jQuery guarantees this even for old browsers that don't support addEventListener).

Comment: Thanks I need to not be worried about older browsers cause we are not supporting them..:)