# How to change event execution order?

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, dom-events

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Close window</title>
</head>
<body>
 <button id="abc" onclick="temp1()">button</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function temp1() {
  alert("temp1");
 };

 function temp2() {
  alert("temp2");
 }

 document.getElementById("abc").addEventListener("click", temp2, false);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

but I want to show "temp2" first, and then show "temp1"

Is that possible? or the event execution order depends on the browser so I can't change it?

thanks for help!!

Comment: Why you do not write an unique function?

Comment: @Marielitos i think i too simplify my question, so I ask another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40821567/how-to-set-the-event-to-be-triggered-first), if you know the answer plz helping me thanks

Comment: I think U need change event model. Event capturing <-> Event bubbling.
check this web:
https://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please review this one:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Close window</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- here is your first AddEventlistener-->
  <button id="abc" onclick="temp1()">button</button>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function temp1() {
      alert("temp1");
    };

    function temp2() {
      alert("temp2");
    }

    /*then here is your second AddEventlistener*/
    var d = document.getElementById("abc");
    d.addEventListener("click", temp2, false);

    /*javascript will execute it in order
      if you want to change the order. remove first EventListener then register new one after. something like this:
    */
     //remove listener
    d.onclick = null;
     //register new
    d.addEventListener('click', temp1);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks, i think your answer is close, but i think i too simplify my question, so I ask another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40821567/how-to-set-the-event-to-be-triggered-first), if you know the answer plz helping me thanks

Comment: You cannot count on the order for older browsers. DOM level 2 specified that there were no specification of order. However, with DOM level 3, you CAN count on the order. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706109/are-event-handlers-in-javascript-called-in-order

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways in which you can guarantee the order here:

```
document.getElementById("abc").addEvenListener("click", function() {
  temp2();
  temp1();
}, false);
```

Another option would be:

```
function temp2() {
  alert();
  temp1(); // call temp1 at the end of temp2
}

document.getElementById("abc").addEventListener("click", temp2, false);
```

Comment: i think i too simplify my question, so I ask another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40821567/how-to-set-the-event-to-be-triggered-first), if you know the answer plz helping me thanks